# How to access a class instance reference name?

Tags: ruby, object

i'm completely new to Ruby and programming in general.

To initialise a class instance I would do the following:

```
ben_smith = Client.new("Ben Smith")
```

As needed I would call the instance reference (not sure if 'reference' is the correct term):

```
ben_smith
=> #<Client:0x007fca2f630de8 @name="Ben Smith">
```

I'm currently learning about Has-Many object relationships and have written a method to allow a class instance of class "Freelancer" to create another class instance of class "Client".

The issue is the Client instances are created but I don't know how to access them independent of the "freelancer_1" instance.

```
class Client

  attr_accessor :name, :company, :freelancer

  def initialize(name, company)
    @name = name
    @company = company
  end

end

class Freelancer

  attr_accessor :name, :skill, :years_of_experience

  def initialize(name, skill, years_of_experience)
    @name = name
    @years_of_experience = years_of_experience
    @skill = skill
    @clients = []
  end

  def add_client_by_name(name, company)
    client = Client.new(name, company)
    @clients << client
    client.freelancer = self
  end

  def clients
    @clients
  end

end
```

Here's my seed code:

```
freelancer_1 = Freelancer.new("Bobby", "Plumber", 10)

freelancer_1.add_client_by_name("Howard Rose", "TNP")
freelancer_1.add_client_by_name("Antony Adel", "Realmless")
freelancer_1.add_client_by_name("Luke Tiller", "SKY")
```

I'd like to access the "clients" like so:

```
luke_tiller.company
```

But there is seemly no "luke_tiller" reference available.
I can access clients via freelancer_1:

```
freelancer_1.clients[2]
```

I'm really unsure

1. if it possible to assign and make available named unique references (client_1, client_2, client_3 etc) using the add_client_by_name method?
2. Is there a way to easily access the Client Instance directly?
3. Why are instance 'references' seemly hidden for both examples given? For the first example, I can call ben_smith but there is mention of this reference if we call ben_smith.

Apologies for the basic questions and my rather long post.
Thank you in advance any help given.

Comment: What is an "instance reference"? There is no such thing in the Ruby Programming Language or in the Ruby Community. Also, what does it mean to "call" an instance reference? The only think in Ruby that you can "call" are methods. (Actually, not even that is true. You can send a message to an object, and Ruby may or may not then call a method on your behalf.) Can you please give a precise, unambiguous, objective, definition of what an "instance reference" is and what "calling" an instance reference means?

Comment: I'm using the term 'instance reference' for the creation of "freelancer_1" below.

I don't know the correct term to use.

    freelancer_1 = Freelancer.new("Bobby", "Plumber", 10)

When I said call I meant simply returning freelancer_1 as below:

    freelancer_1

I am completely new to programming so would appreciate any corrections. For example should I call freelancer_1 a variable or is it the object instance itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sort of "architectural" solution just in case there is an [xy Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) embedded in the question.

- *x* is not having a data structure that stores all Freelancers (and a data structure that stores all clients).
- *y*, the problem in your question, flows from using objects to encapsulate data (this is a good use of objects). This makes  it hard to deal with data in aggregate. For example, writing code that searches *all* Freelancers.

### Data Structure for Aggregates

The data structure uses `Array` for `@clients` and `@freelancers`. It provides `add_freelancer` and `add_client` so that the data type of `@clients` and `@freelancers` can be changed to a file or database without effecting the implementation of `Client` or `Freelancer`.

```
class MyDataStore
  attr_accessor :clients, :freelancers
  def initialize()
    @clients = Array.new
    @freelancers = Array.new
  end

  # hide @freelancers implementation details
  def add_freelancer(f)
    @freelancers.push(f)
  end

  # hide @clients implementation details
  def add_client(c)
    @clients.push(c)
  end

end
```

### Modification of Freelancer.initialize

The `initialize` method now requires a `MyDataStore` object (named 'db'). The newly created `Freelancer` object is added to `db` during initialization.

```
class Freelancer
  attr_reader :name, :db, :skills, :clients

  def initialize(name,db) # db is a new argument
    @name = name
    @skills = Array.new
    @clients = Array.new
    db.add_freelancer(self) # the new Freelancer is added to db
  end
```

#### Abstract over @skills and @clients implementation

While we are thinking about it, why not?

```
  #abstract over implementation
  def add_skill(skill)
    @skills.push(skill)
  end

  def add_client(client)
    @clients.push(client)
  end

end
```

### Example environment

A simple application of the code. Instead of naming each object ourselves, we just store the object. Most of the time this is what we want at creation.

```
db = MyDataStore.new
Freelancer.new('a', db)
Freelancer.new('b', db)
Freelancer.new('c', db)
Freelancer.new('d', db)
Freelancer.new('a', db)
```

**Interactive**
Notice that `db.freelancers` is an aggregate of objects. Each object is uniquely identified by it's hash. There are two different freelancers named 'a' and it's not a problem *(yet)*.

```
Irb(main):10:0> db.freelancers
=> [#<Freelancer:0x00000001b1dd38 @clients=[], @name="a", @skills=[]>,
    #<Freelancer:0x00000001b1dc98 @clients=[], @name="b", @skills=[]>,
    #<Freelancer:0x00000001b1db30 @clients=[], @name="c", @skills=[]>,
    #<Freelancer:0x00000001b1d9f0 @clients=[], @name="d", @skills=[]>, 
    #<Freelancer:0x00000001b1c988 @clients=[], @name="a", @skills=[]>]
```

#### Getting a freelancer by name

*Warning: this code relies on implementation details.* This could be hidden

```
irb(main):907:0> db.freelancers.select {|f| f.name == 'a'}
=> [#<Freelancer:0x00000001b1dd38 @clients=[], @name="a", @skills=[]>,
    #<Freelancer:0x00000001b1c988 @clients=[], @name="a", @skills=[]>]
```

#### Adding a skill and a client

*Warning: this code relies on implementation details.* It also assumes that the `Client` class has been implemented.

```
# add @skill 'Ruby' to freelancer named 'b'
irb(main):10:0> db.freelancers.select {|f| f.name == 'b'}[0].add_skill('Ruby')
=> ["Ruby"]

# check freelancer named 'b' has skill 'Ruby'
irb(main):11:0> db.freelancers.select {|f| f.name == 'b'}
=> [#<Freelancer:0x00000001f16e58 @clients=[], @name="b", @skills=["Ruby"]>]

# uses '\' to span two lines for readability here on stackoverflow
irb(main):195:0> db.freelancers.select {|f| f.name == 'b'} \ 
                 [0].add_client(Client.new('Best Client', db))
=> [#<Client:0x00000001ed9af8 @name="Best Client", @skills=[]>]

#check that 'Best Client' has been added to db.clients
irb(main):196:0> db.clients
=> [#<Client:0x00000001ed9af8 @name="Best Client", @skills=[]>]

#check that 'Best Client' has been added to freelancer named 'b'
irb(main):197:0> db.freelancers.select {|f| f.name == 'b'} [0]
=> #<Freelancer:0x00000001e096f0 @name="b", 
                                 @skills=[], 
                                 @clients=[#<Client:0x00000001ed9af8 @name="Best Client", @skills=[]>]>
```

### Discussion

It is worth emphasizing **we are always storing and passing objects** and avoiding assigning objects to variables whenever possible. When it is not possible to avoid assigning an object to a variable, we try to do it temporarily in a block, for example `{|f| f.name == 'b'}`.

- It is also important to acknowledge **data storage and retrieval is hard.** And here we are designing our own *object oriented data store*. There is a scale at which this makes sense.
- There are applications where maintaining the necessary data integrity using an external database (SQLite, mySQL, Postgres) makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough and illuminating response.

I am still mulling the concepts but the key take-away I have is:

1 - in the case we design our own object orientated store it would be a good idea to create a unique identifier on initialization of an object. 
2 - an external database could also be used to generate unique IDs. This would enable easy retrieval when that object is required.

Comment: @jolee You are welcome. Each Ruby object gets an object ID when created. The object ID's of active objects are unique. https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/object_id This might be enough *data integrity* for your use case. If it isn't, that may be a reason to use an external database because external databases are designed to address data integrity issues and to provide clear tradeoffs. Again, I think this stuff is hard in an absolute sense and I'm still learning.

Comment: @jolee Designing an object store is likely to be a great learning experience. For a simple application, it can be sound engineering practice: simple solution to a simple problem. As the application gains complexity, the engineering tradeoffs of the approach may become less beneficial. Also the pace of learning may go down because the best way to understand the complex problems and tradeoffs of data storage is by looking at a well designed system.

Comment: @jolee The big concept in my answer is adding an object that handles data objects in aggregate. So there are two sorts of objects. One encapsulates individual data like Client and Freelancer. The other catalogs all Clients and Freelancers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of index-based access, you could add a new method in the `Freelancer` class like:

```
class Freelancer
  def find_client_by_name(name)
    @clients.find { |client| client.name == name }
  end
end
```

Now you could do:

```
luke_tiller = freelancer_1.find_client_by_name('Luke Tiller')
puts luke_tiller.company
# SKY
```